# NavigationBar in react-native 0.1.17 navigator

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I just upgraded my react-native 0.1.15 app to 0.1.17 version and I've been getting a 'Unable to download JS bundle error'. I've managed to trace the error in my code:

```
var SportsSocial = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
        this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    },
  RouteMapper: function(route, navigationOperations, onComponentRef) {
    _navigator = navigationOperations;

    if (route.name === 'login') {
      return (
        <LoginView navigator={navigationOperations} events={this.eventEmitter} />
      );
    } else if (route.name === 'main') {
      return (
        <NewsView navigator={navigationOperations} events={this.eventEmitter}/>
      );
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var initialRoute = {name: 'login'};
    return (
      <Navigator
            style={styles.container}
        configureScene={() => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid}
        navigationBarHidden={false}
        (==>)navigationBar=<NavigationBar events={this.eventEmitter}/>
        renderScene={this.RouteMapper}
        initialRoute={initialRoute}
      />
    );
  }
});
```

I get the error when I try to add a navigationBar to my Navigator instance. I didn't have issues with it in the 0.1.15 version.

Even something as simple as the following line gives me the same error:

```
navigationBar=<View />
```

Have I somehow misread the docs and it worked by mistake in the previous version?
The following can be found in the docs at [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html:](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html)

```
navigationBar node 
Optionally provide a navigation bar that persists across scene transitions
```

Is there some other way I should be getting at including a custom navigation bar into my app?

Edit: I have tested all my required components (which are LoginView, NewsView and NavigationBar), and they all work. The issue is only adding the NavigationBar to the Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution is very simple:

```
navigationBar={<NavigationBar events={this.eventEmitter}/>}
```

A little confused as to why, but ok.